# After taking picture returns to previoius activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Here i am trying to launch the camera and take a pic and then set it to a ImageView, but I am being returned to the previous activity after clicking the pic. Here is my code:

```
public void launchCamera(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resCode,Intent data){
    if(reqCode == 1 && resCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ImageView relativeLayout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageTaken);
        if(photo==null){
         relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        else {
            relativeLayout.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try once this example.If you get same problem then tell me https://www.dropbox.com/s/w29sljy0zpwwm61/MyApplication.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the support. The issue has been resolved. Actually the problem was in a different call. I was having a MediaPlayer finish() call that was causing the problem in onPause() method. However, with FragmentActivity also it is running, and i dont need any super call too.

Comment: There is a new issue now. After taking the pic if i rotate the screen the pic is restored to the old one. May be because i have not saved it. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need declare permission in manifest file.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Your code looks good, please note that you will get a Thumbnail image.

Please follow the instructions mentioned here, http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html . All the best

Comment: You shouldn't have to add permission to use another camera app opened from `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment it will return to parent Activity.Otherwise below link help you.

http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/02/multiple-choose-custom-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this. the difference is the  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); which is necessary when using onActivityResult in fragment

```
public void launchCamera(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}



      @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap1 = null;
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    bitmap1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    ImageView relativeLayout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageTaken);
            if(photo==null){
             relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
            else {
                relativeLayout.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }


    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

------------------layout_photoactivity.xml-----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_click_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Select Photo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

-----------PhotoActivity.class----------

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PhotoActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView1;
    TextView tv_click_photo;
     public static final String SHAre_PREFERENCES = "Prefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_photoactivity);

        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv_click_photo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_click_photo);

        tv_click_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Camera_Activity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

                }
            });

    }


     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
     switch(requestCode) {

     case 1:
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                System.out.println("result:"+result);
              SharedPreferences data_preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHAre_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);   
                String Image_Path= data_preferences.getString("Image_Path", "Notavailble");
                String imgstr = data_preferences.getString("data", "Notavailble");

                File sel = new File(Image_Path);
                 String file = sel.getAbsolutePath().substring(sel.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sel.getAbsolutePath());
                 imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
            break;

     }
     }
}
```

------------------------------activity_camera.xml----------------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <SurfaceView 
       android:id="@+id/preview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       />
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
     >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:onClick="onCancelClick"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#EDEDED"
        android:textSize="12dp"
     />
    <Button 
         android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="CAPTURE"
        android:onClick="onSnapClick"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#EDEDED"
        android:textSize="12dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

-----------------------Camera_Activity.class----------

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;



import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Camera_Activity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback{

    Camera mCamera;
    SurfaceView mPreview;
    String path, dirpath;
    //static int i = 0;
    String Image_Path="",StrBase64="";
    Button btn_cancel,btn_capture;

    public static final String SHAre_PREFERENCES = "Prefs";
    int flag=0;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        btn_cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        btn_capture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);


        if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) { 
            // Activity was brought to front and not created, 
            // Thus finishing this will get us to the last viewed activity 
            finish(); 
            return; 
        } 

        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mCamera.release();
        Log.d("CAMERA", "Destroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

public void onCancelClick(View v)
{
    if(flag == 0)
    {
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent(Camera_Activity.this,PhotoActivity.class);

        if (getParent() == null) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        } else {
            getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        }
        finish();

    }

}

public void onSnapClick(View v)
{
    if(flag == 0)
    {
        btn_capture.setClickable(false);
        mCamera.takePicture(this, null, null, this);

    }
    else
    {
         mCamera.startPreview();
         btn_capture.setText("CAPTURE");
            btn_cancel.setText("CANCEL");
        flag =0;
    }


}


    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.startPreview();
        Random j = new Random();


        int ii =  j.nextInt(1000);
         File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         System.out.println("sd:"+sd);
        Image_Path = sd.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/Pic/pic"+ ii + ".jpg";
        System.out.println("Image_Path--------------:"+Image_Path);
        path = "pic" + ii + ".jpg";
        try {
              SharedPreferences data_preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHAre_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);   
            Editor editor = data_preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Image_Path",Image_Path);
            String str;

                str = new String(data, "UTF-8");

            editor.putString("data",str);           

                editor.commit();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }   
        if(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED != null)//true if sd card is mounted (xternal)
        {
            //Here we chose external storage
            File dir = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/Pic");
            if(!dir.exists())
            {
            if (dir.mkdirs()) {  
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,  
                "Directory successfully created!",  
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
            toast.show();  
           }
            else
           {  

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,  
                "Directory creation failed!",  
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                  toast.show();  
           }  
            }
            File file = new File(dir.getPath().toString(), path);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(Camera_Activity.this, "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // handle exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //Here we chose internal storage
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(path, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        btn_capture.setText("RETAKE");
        btn_cancel.setText("USE");
         btn_capture.setClickable(true);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        flag =1;


    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
        //params.setPreviewSize(selected.width, selected.height);
        //mCamera.setParameters(params);

    //  mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        params.set("orientation", "landscape");
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("PREVIEW", "surfaceDestroyed");
    }


    public void onShutter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml are

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Comment: This code will be an alternate solution ,not answer to the original question. As well as there is no explanation provided with answer

Comment: after clicking the pic  onPictureTaken function will call, so here save the image in sd card and then save path of image in SharedPreferences and with the help of below code you can return to previous activity

       Intent returnIntent = new Intent(Camera_Activity.this,PhotoActivity.class);
  
  if (getParent() == null) {
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
  } else {
      getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
  }
  finish();

Comment: explain this in your answer not comment

Comment: Check my above code, I have alredy mensioned it in Camera_Activity.class